# How to prove $e^{1/e}$ is irrational?

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

How do we prove $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ is irrational ?
Also how do we show it is transcendental ?

The number $\eta = \exp(\exp(-1))$ occurs naturally in the context of tetration and power towers.

Let $h(x) = x^{x^{x^{...}}}$ then $x = \eta$ is the largest real $x$ such that $h(x)$ converges. Btw $h(\eta) = e$.

I know $\exp(\pi)$ is irrational (even transcendental) and this looks similar.

Im not even sure the Geldfond-Sneider theorem helps here, or the $h$ function.

Comment: It is unknown if $e^{1/e}$ is rational or not, let alone transcendental.

Comment: Im "sure" it is. Do you have references for your claim that there is no proof ? @Elliot G

Comment: @user254665 $e^{\pi}$ has been long established as irrational (and transcendental) - it's actually a simple application of Gelfond-Schneider as applied to $(-1)^{-i}$. It's $\pi^e, \pi^{\pi},, e^e$ and even $\frac{e}{\pi}$ and $e\pi$ that have an unknown "status". (For the last two, the irrationality/transcendence of one immediately establishes the same of the other).

Comment: I apologize.It's not rational else $e^{\pi i}=-1$ would be transcendental (Gelfond).

Comment: @mick, you are "sure"?! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To give you an example of when an irrational number raised to an irrational power is rational, here goes:

$$e^{\ln(2)}=2$$

Can you believe me when I say $\ln(2)$ is irrational, hence I have created a counter-example to your logic.

However, this problem is easily misunderstood as well:

$$e^m, m=0,1,2,3,\dots$$

Whether or not that is rational or irrational is not so easily found, for example, $(\sqrt{2})^2=2$ so even if the base is irrational, the result may be rational.

One knows that $\sqrt[b]a=\frac pq$ is irrational if $b$ is a positive whole number and $a$ is not a power of $b$ because you can't write it as a rational fraction $\frac pq$, power both sides by $b$, and get $a$.

Determining such simple things are a lot harder than it seems.